# How can I launch an android app on upon pressing the volume up or volume down button?

Tags: android, android-hardware

I have a requirements in a personal safety app where a user has to launch an app as soon as possible via pressing the volume up or volume down button. What is the procedure to add this functionality?

Comment: really an interesting  question!!

Comment: if my answer is feasible than raise and accept that we can close it.

Answer (score 14):

There is no broadcast event for volume change.

However, [there is an undocumented action](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1226792) called "[`android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/java/android/media/AudioManager.java#L139)" which you could use, but it probably won't work on all devices/versions so [**it is not recommended**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8974510/318508).

Using other buttons (e.g. [media buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10537649/318508)) would be possible though.

**EDIT:** Code sample (using the undocumented action):

AndroidManifest.xml

```
...
<receiver android:name="VolumeChangeReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
...
```

VolumeChangeReceiver.java

```
public class VolumeChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION")) {
            int newVolume = intent.getIntExtra("android.media.EXTRA_VOLUME_STREAM_VALUE", 0);
            int oldVolume = intent.getIntExtra("android.media.EXTRA_PREV_VOLUME_STREAM_VALUE", 0);
            if (newVolume != oldVolume) {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(context, YourActivity.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793221/how-my-app-can-unlock-screen-programatically) if you want to unlock the screen when launching your app.

Comment: @MuhammadMaqsoodurRehman I added a code sample (based on my first and second links), I don't have the SDK now so it's not tested. Keep in mind that since this is an unofficial method, it will not work on all devices/versions.

Answer (score -6):

I've used this code to listen for the volume button before,

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)){
        //Do something
    }
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)){
        //Do something
    }
    return true;
}
```

This method gets event of volume up and down.

Comment: hi deepali he wants to launch app itself while this code may work from inside the acticity while before app launch is it possible??

Comment: @MuhammadMaqsoodurRehman than theres are two posibilities, either you need to do something with firm-ware or else you can launch app first time normally and from the next time you can launch with the help of broadcast receiver.