# BroadcastReceiver in android not listening when the app is closed

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I created a BroadcastReceiver called MyReceiver to listen for volume change event. It works fine when the app is running. But, when i close the app, it stops listening to broadcasts.

Here's the registered broadcast receiver in the manifest file.

```html
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver"
          android:enabled="true"
          android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: create a service. It will help you to run the receiver while the app is closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I launch an android app on upon pressing the volume up or volume down button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086480/how-can-i-launch-an-android-app-on-upon-pressing-the-volume-up-or-volume-down-bu)

Comment: I tried that one too. I had a service. In its onCreate() i registered for a broadcast. But the same problem persists.

Comment: @dhawal My problem is different.

Comment: update your service,receiver and activity code it may give some clue

Comment: can u copy the full manifest here?

Comment: Apparently, this issue is specific to devices. It works in Samsung and doesn't in Redmi. Any idea how to handle this?