# Run an application when clicking volume button

Tags: android

In my android project,I want to run my application application when my volume button is clicked.But when I click  volume button for media player or brightness change I don't want to run my application.How can I achieve this?

Comment: you have to use broadcast manager to do that

Comment: But I have to consider cases of media player

Comment: how can device differentiate when you want to change brightness and when to run app.??

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21087442/5545429)