# How to detect home-button press, preferably with an intent-filter?

Tags: java, android

I want my app to execute a piece of code whenever the homebutton is pressed. This should also happen, when the app itself isn't currently open. I have found a way to do this with volume buttons:

[How can I launch an android app on upon pressing the volume up or volume down button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086480/how-can-i-launch-an-android-app-on-upon-pressing-the-volume-up-or-volume-down-bu)

But I need it to work with the home button. Setting the app as a launcher doesn't work, as it won't work on the lockscreen then.

Comment: This is not possible, sorry.

Comment: But why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Eselfar my friend has a phone with a virtual home button. He asked me if there was a way I could make it taptic (so vibrate if he presses it, just like the iPhone), but there is no setting for it.

Comment: You can do Settings -> Sound -> Vibrate on tap. It activates vibrations when you press anything (so not the home button only so I don't know if this is what your friend is looking for). But otherwise you can't do that with an app, you need to modify the system itself.