# Is there a way by which we could run application in background in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I want to run my application in background and when the volume buttons are pressed (a specific combination) then my application would open.

Comment: Please provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

Android?

There is no need to "run the application in background". What you can do is [register a receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21087442/750510) on `android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION` event and then use [method channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) to convey the event from the native part of the app to Flutter. However, **note that `android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION` is not documented and you should use it with caution**.