# Google Now takes bluetooth broadcast

Tags: android, bluetooth

i try to get bluetooth button key press with the popular code from the web.
also in this thread [Capture media button on Android >=4.0 (works on 2.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537184/capture-media-button-on-android-4-0-works-on-2-3)

but google now responds to it (although my app is in foreground) cannot achieve this.
what i did:
(env nexus 4, android 4.4.4)

1. turn off google now setting preferences 'bluetooth headset recording' (not sure the exact name cause i'm not using it in english - looks like a bug - it is off and still google search is responding
2. turn off google now at all - i think it is another bug - it is off and still responds to to my BlueTooth button.

in my app:

3. have correct BT permission
4. in manifest file - register recevier by:
5. or previous in other way in my app onCreate() method:
       mediaButton = new MediaButtonIntentReceiver();

   ```
   IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
   intentFilter.setPriority(IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY-1);
   registerReceiver(mediaButton, intentFilter);
   ```

or this
    ((AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE)).registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(new ComponentName(this,
                MediaButtonIntentReceiver.class));

any suggestions? please help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to partially hack this by setting:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

although i cannot still register receiver for this intent "android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND", i do not undersand it.