# Fail to Intercept Bluetooth headset media button events

Tags: c#, bluetooth, xamarin.android

Im trying to catch bluetooth headset media buttons events (say the "next" button), on a c# Xamarin android app.
i copied the code found at https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22122/headset-button-event-android-c, but clicking the headset's button starts spotify on a phone that has it installed, and google's "play music" app on a phone that doesnt. either way my "OnReceive" event never gets fired.
please see the commented-out code for all variations i already tried, to no avail.

played with the priority value, too.

```cs
got this under the manifest's <application> tag:

<receiver android:name="BroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

and these permissions:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" /> 

and this is my MainActivity class:

[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        [Obsolete]
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            var am = (AudioManager)this.GetSystemService(AudioService);
            var componentName = new ComponentName(PackageName, new MyMediaButtonBroadcastReceiver().ComponentName);
            am.RegisterMediaButtonEventReceiver(componentName);
        }

        public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
        {
            MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            int id = item.ItemId;
            if (id == Resource.Id.action_settings)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

[BroadcastReceiver] //(Enabled = true, Exported = false)
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"})] // , BluetoothHeadset.ActionAudioStateChanged, BluetoothHeadset.ActionVendorSpecificHeadsetEvent
    public class MyMediaButtonBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public string ComponentName { get { return Class.Name; } }

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent.Action != Intent.ActionMediaButton)
                return;

            var keyEvent = (KeyEvent)intent.GetParcelableExtra(Intent.ExtraKeyEvent);

            switch (keyEvent.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keycode.MediaPlay:
                    break;
                case Keycode.MediaPlayPause:
                    break;
                case Keycode.MediaNext:
                    break;
                case Keycode.MediaPrevious:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

got no errors, but nothing else happens, either.

Comment: one last note, im using API 28

Comment: try to set  `am.Mode = Mode.Normal; `,and capture the event with the  `keyDown ` method triggered in your activity

Answer (score 0):

Thanx Leo for trying to help, found the answer in this post [How register Broadcast Receiver for media button in Oreo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48840827/how-register-broadcast-receiver-for-media-button-in-oreo/50678833#50678833) - mainly using MediaSession and playing AudioTrack, and not the (apparently deprecated?) BroadcastReceiver.